# NF (Noise Figure) calculation - task

Tags: frequency, radio, signal-to-noise

> In a 622 Mbps radio-link interface, it was assumed that the BER would
> be 10^-10 when the signal-to-noise ratio at the receiver point is 7.8
> dB, while its sensitivity for a fixed modulation-code scheme is
> -75dBm. To meet these conditions, use a receiver with a maximum noise figure of about.... ? 
>  Choose among and prove with calculations.
>
> - 5 dB
> - 2 dB
> - 3 dB
> - 6 dB?

My problem is the lack of skills to count this task.

On the other hand, I don't know the bandwidth either - I can only assume something, e.g. 633 MHz or another value (possible for the 622 Mbps value).  I think the formula should be used: Sensitivity=10×log10(kTB)+NF+C⁄N.

However, I won't use the BER information here then - since it's given it's probably necessary to use it. How to solve this task correctly?

Comment: The throughput data rate defines the minimum bandwidth.

Comment: So what is the value of bandwidth and the answer to the task?

Comment: This sounds like homework.

Comment: No, I have problem with that and I'm waiting for helping me!

Comment: 2dB is easily possible to achieve in an LNA. Unless really strapped for cash, there's no reason to deliberately choose something noisier. It also gives you margin for degrading it with a lossy cable to the Rx antenna, or a detuned or otherwise compromised Rx antenna. To do the sum you've been asked to do, you need to know something about the transmitter, or the link budget, which you don't appear to have.

Comment: Ok, but I need to support it with calculations and mathematics - a formula.